# circle method estimate integral over minor arcs

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have given the following lemma:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and let $a, q, z$ be such that
$$
1 \leqslant a \leqslant q \leqslant B^{2}, \quad \operatorname{gcd}(a, q)=1, \quad|z| \leqslant \frac{1}{q^{2}}
$$
Then we have
$$
S\left(\frac{a}{q}+z\right) \ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n+\varepsilon} q^{-\frac{n}{24}} \min \left\{1,|z| B^{4}\right\}^{-\frac{n}{24}}
$$

Furthermore the major arcs are defined as follows:

$\mathfrak{M}_{q, a}(\Delta)=\left[\frac{a}{q}-B^{-4+\Delta}, \frac{a}{q}+B^{-4+\Delta}\right]$

for $1 \leqslant a \leqslant q$ with $(a, q)=1$ and $q \leqslant B^{\Delta} .$

With $\Delta$ being a small positive parameter.

The full set of major arcs is given by
\begin{equation}
    \mathfrak{M}(\Delta)=\bigcup_{1 \leqslant q \leqslant B^{\Delta}} \bigcup_{1 \leqslant a \leqslant q \atop \operatorname{gcd}(a, q)=1} \mathfrak{M}_{q, a}(\Delta)
\end{equation}

We define the minor arcs modulo 1 as:
$\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)=[0,1] \backslash \mathfrak{M}(\Delta)$.

Now I want to estimate the minor arcs. So let $\alpha \in \mathfrak{m}(\Delta)$. By Dirichlet's approximation theorem we can find integers $a$ and $q$ such that $(a,q)=1$ and $1 \leq a \leq q \leq B^2$.
Therefore $|\alpha-\frac{a}{q}| \leq \frac{1}{B^2q}$.
From the definition of the major arcs we see that for $\alpha \in \mathfrak{m}(\Delta) = [0,1] \setminus \mathfrak{M}(\Delta)$ we may assume that $q > B^{\Delta}$ or $|q\alpha - a| > qB^{-4+\Delta}$.

Writing $\alpha=\frac{a}{q}+z$ we can now apparently conclude from the lemma that:
$$
\begin{gathered}
    \int_{\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)}|S(\alpha)| \mathrm{d} \alpha \ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n+\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leqslant B^{2}} q^{1-\frac{n}{24}} \int_{\frac{-1}{q B^{2}}}^{\frac{1}{q B^{2}}} \min \left\{1,|z| B^{4}\right\}^{-\frac{n}{24}} \mathrm{~d} z \\
    \ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n-4-\Delta\left(\frac{n}{24}-2\right)+\varepsilon}
\end{gathered}
$$
under the assumption that $n>48$.

Would the following make sense for reasoning the first estimation?

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \int_{\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)}|S(\alpha)| \mathrm{d} \alpha &=\sum_{q \leq B^2} \sum_{a=1 \atop (a,q)=1}^{q} \int_{\mathfrak{m}(a,q)} |S(\alpha)| d\alpha \\
    & \ll_{\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leq B^2} \sum_{a=1 \atop (a,q)=1}^{q} \int_{-\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}^{\frac{1}{B^{2}q}} B^{n+\varepsilon} q^{-\frac{n}{24}} \min\{1, |z|B^4\}^{-\frac{n}{24}} d z \\
    &= B^{n+\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leq B^2}  q^{1-\frac{n}{24}} \int_{-\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}^{\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}   \min\{1, |z|B^4\}^{-\frac{n}{24}} d z
\end{aligned}
$$

For the last estimation I tried this now:

$$\int_{\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)}|S(\alpha)| \mathrm{d} \alpha \ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n+\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leq B^2} q^{1-\frac{n}{24}} \int_{\frac{-1}{qB^2}}^{\frac{1}{qB^2}} \min\{1, |z|B^4\}^{-n/24} dz$$

We have to distinguish two cases:

1. for $|z| < B^{-4}$ we know that the minimum is $|z|B^4$ and therefore we can estimate the integral using the maximum 1.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)}|S(\alpha)| \mathrm{d} \alpha &\ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n+\varepsilon} \sum_{B^{\Delta} < q \leq B^2} q^{1-\frac{n}{24}} \int_{0}^{B^{-4}} 1 dz \\
&\ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n-4-\Delta(\frac{n}{24}-2)+\varepsilon} 
\end{aligned}
$$

2. for $|z| > B^{-4}$ we know that the minimum is 1 and therefore we can estimate the integral using the maximum $|z|B^4$.

$$
\int_{\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)}|S(\alpha)| \mathrm{d} \alpha \ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n+\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leq B^2} q^{1-\frac{n}{24}} \int_{B^{-4}}^{\frac{1}{qB^2}} (|z|B^4)^{\frac{-n}{24}} dz 
$$

We can use that $|z|=z$ and substitute $\tilde{z}=zB^4$. Then we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \int_{\mathfrak{m}(\Delta)}|S(\alpha)| \mathrm{d} \alpha &\ll_{\varepsilon} B^{n+\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leq B^2} q^{1-\frac{n}{24}} \int_{1}^{B^{2}q^{-1}} (\tilde{z})^{\frac{-n}{24}} B^{-4} d \tilde{z} \\
    &=B^{n-4+\varepsilon} \sum_{q \leq B^2} \left(\frac{B^{2-\frac{n}{12}}}{1-\frac{n}{24}}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{n}{24}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

And in the first case I would get what I need. But is the second case really smaller? Am I missing something and does, what I did, even hold true?

I posted this question before here but I didn't get any response so far. I hope it's ok to post it here as well. Any hint or help would be much appreciated. :)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201723/estimation-integral-over-minor-arcs

Comment: How is $S(\alpha)$ defined? I'm pretty sure I know but I just want to clarify.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. The definition of the complete exponential sums is: 
$$S_{q, a}:=\sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \left(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}\right)^n} e_{q}(a f(\mathbf{x}))$$, for $a, q$ coprime such that $1 \leqslant a \leqslant q$
And we have the following lemma: 
 Let $a, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $1 \leq a \leq q \leq B$ and $(a, q)=1.$
 Then we have
 $$
 S\left(\frac{a}{q}+z\right)=q^{-n} B^{n} S_{q, a} I\left(z B^{d}\right)+O\left(q B^{n-1}\left(1+|z| B^{d}\right)\right)
 $$
 where
 $$
 I(\gamma):=\int_{\mathbf{t} \in[-1,1]^{n}} e(\gamma f(\mathbf{t})) \mathrm{d} \mathbf{t}
 $$

Comment: And $d=4$ in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)  I think this is what I need to do. I sadly still don't see how I get that the integral is $\approx B^{-4}$. Can I just integrate from $-B^{-4}$ to $B^{-4}$? And is $\int_{-\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}^{\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}   \min\{1, |z|B^4\}^{-\frac{n}{24}} d z$ the same as $\int_{-\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}^{\frac{1}{B^{2}q}}   \max\{1, \frac{1}{|z|B^4}\}^{\frac{n}{24}} d z$?
Could I estimate the sum as follows: 
$\sum_{B^{\Delta} < q \leq B^2}  q^{1-\frac{n}{24}} \ll \frac{1}{B^{\Delta(n/24-1)}} \ll B^{-\Delta(n/24-2)}$ ?
Or did I get that completely wrong now?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and thought for some reason the exponent was inside the min in the statement of the lemma… Are you sure the lemma above is stated correctly?

Comment: No worries. Sadly I'm pretty sure that's how the lemma is stated here https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:d2d70166-bd9d-4a6b-a86c-7c335983309d it would be on p.148 :) maybe I missed something else?

Comment: thank you for the context!!!! that helps so much --- ok so first off the last estimation before "under the assumption that $n > 48$" in your question isn't correct (just consider the integral over z with $|z|\ll B^{-4}$ and if i'm not being stupid again i believe you only save a $B^{-2}$), and Browning also has the same mistake in the pdf you shared. (it's one of these things where it's kind of expected and totally fine in these uber technical writeups, certainly i don't blame him or anyone else who has these little typos!!!!) so here's how i think you fix everything:

Comment: i think lemma 8.7 is too lossy to just apply (he uses $|z|\ll q^{-2}$, and i think that's too crude for this), so instead just insert (8.18) directly into the minor arc integral, that gives you three terms to consider (cause $a + b + c\ll \max(a,b,c)$ when $a,b,c>0$), and i believe the only time you'll use the minor arc restriction that either $q\gg B^\Delta$ or else $|z|\ll B^{-4+\Delta}$ is when bounding the second term (the one w/ $\left(q|z|\max(1, \frac{1}{|z|B^4})\right)^{n/24}$). also to bound the first term and get a bit more than $B^{-4}$ savings you'll use $n\geq 49$ i believe

Comment: sorry, i made a typo (Lol), i meant to say consider the integral over $|z|\gg B^{-4}$ in the second to last comment in order to see that you only save a $B^{-2}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I also thought that I would only save $B^{-2}$ for $|z| \gg B^{-4}$ but I just figured that what's written in Browning's book has to be correct and I did something wrong. I don't really understand why I shouldn't be able to apply the lemma tho. Since I know that $q \leq B^2$ and I know that $|z| \leq \frac{1}{qB^2}$ I have $|z| \leq \frac{1}{q^2}$ and the lemma should be applicable, no? What am I getting wrong? And can I estimate the sum like I did it in the previous comment :)?

Comment: And what do you think would be the correct estimation then? :)

Comment: oh yeah to be clear you can apply the lemma, i'm just saying it seems to end up giving a weaker bound than what you're after. im just eyeballing but i think the bounds on the three terms are: $B^{n-4+\epsilon - (n/8 - 2)}$ for the first term, $B^{n-4+\epsilon - (n/12 - 4)}$ for the second term (the one with the max), and then the third term splits into two cases: for the $q\gg B^\Delta$ guys, $B^{n-4+\epsilon - \Delta (n/24 - 2)}$, and for the $q\ll B^\Delta$ guys (now using $|z|\gg B^{-4+\Delta}$), $B^{n-4+\epsilon - \Delta(n/24 - 1)}$. but yeah im just eyeballing so lemme know what you get!!

Comment: I edited my question now with my latest tries. I think my main issue is evaluating this integral $\int_{B^{-4}}^{\frac{1}{qB^2}} (|z|B^4)^{\frac{-n}{24}} dz$. Any help on my "new" second case would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: I'm also trying to do it your way now @alpoge... but does the second term not split into two cases as well? I got the bound for the first term and in the third term I got the bound for the case where $q \gg B^{\Delta}$ as well... but how do you get the second case for the third term and what did you do exactly for the second term?